# AWS Elastic BeanStalk php.ini file update

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, config

I would like to increase my minimum upload filesize from 2MB to 64 MB for my php web application..  I have a config file stored in an .ebextensions directory.. While deploying to aws, an error occurred:

The configuration file .ebextensions/yep.config in application version try10 contains invalid YAML or JSON. YAML exception: while scanning a simple key in "", line 7, column 7: upload_max_filesize = 64M ^ could not found expected ':' in "", line 8, column 7: post_max_size = 64M ^ , JSON exception: Unexpected character (f) at position 0.. Update the configuration file.

Below is my config file that I am starting out with.  I have spend 8 hours troubleshooting with no luck.  Any help will be very much obliged.

```
files:
"/etc/php.ini":
  mode: "000755"
  owner: root
  group: root
  content: |
  upload_max_filesize = 64M
  post_max_size = 64M
```

Comment: Your php.ini path is the issue I guess the path for php.ini is "/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini" most of the times. Ans after you update you will have to restart apache too.

Comment: Ok I will try that..

Comment: yeah its still giving me the same error.. so something is wrong with the code

Comment: Do you have apache on you server?

Comment: yes its apache 2.0 handler

Comment: Can you SSH into the instance?

Comment: I am connected through mindterm right now but I dont know any commands

Comment: Ok So it will be difficult for you Did you check this options http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.container.html#create_deploy_PHP.container.console.php

Comment: Try one thing change that path to /etc/php.d/project.ini and the mode to 000644 and then try if it works?

Comment: I will have to see if I can change it over mindterm.. I am connected

Comment: ok I will try that..

Comment: That didnt work either.. so I am going to see if I can find a command for mindterm..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am using this successfully in an Elastic Beanstalk application. Just put the following into your yep.config file inside of your .ebextensions directory in the root of your application.

```
files:
  "/etc/php.d/project.ini" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      upload_max_filesize=64M
      post_max_size=64M
```

Comment: Also make sure to use spaces instead of tabs and make sure you don't have any hidden characters being placed in the file that could cause issues with AWS parsing out the needed values.

Comment: I really appreciate it man.. It worked.. Thank you once again!!

Comment: Just an FYI, if you have multiple .config files within .ebextensions, they will be executed in alphabetical order.  Same for PHP .ini files - PHP will scan all files ending in .ini in alphabetical order.

Comment: @infohound thanks for the fix, it is working seamlessly fine. Hoping AWS starts a good document around .ebextensions

Comment: Question: What does the "mode" number mean? I have seen a couple places where "000644" is used in this scenario, but their docs show a different example and use "000755". I can't find anywhere AWS says what this number means. It's 2023(!) and their documentation is still useless. Here is their entire doc on extending php.ini (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-configuration-phpini.html).