# Laravel on AWS: Log file permissions problem

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm having a very frustrating time deploying a Laravel webapp to Amazon Web Services Elastic Beanstalk. Some times it's fine, but about 50% of the time I get the following crash:

> The stream or file "/var/app/current/storage/logs/laravel-2019-10-18.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

(Where the date is the current date.)

Sure enough, when I SSH into the server I can see the permissions for that particular log file are set to `root:root`.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   3400 Oct 18 13:39 laravel-2019-10-18.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 webapp webapp    0 Oct 18 13:39 laravel.log
```

If I change the owner to `webapp:webapp` then the app works fine again. Likewise if I delete the log file the site works fine again... until the next deployment.

My question is how I can prevent this from happening. Disable all logs? Change the permissions during deployment? Is it only because debug is set to "true"?

Here's my `deploy.config`. Is something wrong or missing?

```
container_commands:
  01-migrations:
    command: "php artisan migrate --force"
  02-import:
    command: "php artisan import:initial-data"

files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_make_storage_writable.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      echo "Making /storage writeable..."
      chmod -R 755 /var/app/current/storage

      if [ ! -f /var/app/current/storage/logs/laravel.log ]; then
          echo "Creating /storage/logs/laravel.log..."
          touch /var/app/current/storage/logs/laravel.log
          sudo chown -R webapp:webapp /var/app/current/storage/logs
          sudo chmod -R ug+w /var/app/current/storage/logs

      fi


#https://serverfault.com/a/669547/24863
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_restart_workers.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      echo "Spawn worker..."
      nohup php /var/app/current/artisan queue:work >/dev/null 2>&1 &

  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/publishlogs.d/laravel-logs.conf":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      /var/app/current/storage/logs/*.log

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/38751749/199700
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/https_redirect.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      RewriteEngine on
      <If "-n '%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}' && %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} != 'https'">
      RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
      </If>

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/38600025/199700
  "/etc/php.d/project.ini" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      upload_max_filesize=10M
      post_max_size=32M
```

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens because you're running a `php artisan` command that writes to the logs as root. Taking a look at the initial contents of `laravel-2019-10-18.log` should give a clue as to which command is involved.